# Simple NetBeans servlet, button won't work

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm starting off in NetBeans, and implementing a form which, when you press the "submit" button, performs validation and tells you if the data entered is correct. I haven't gotten to the validation part yet, for the moment all I'm trying to do is, when the "submit" button is clicked, a message pops up. I'm having trouble here, I have a feeling its a quick simple fix but I'm not finding anything on message boards or documentation.

EDIT - Thanks guys! was missing the "form" tag. I figured it would be simple, thanks again for your help everyone!

Here's my index.html file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Client Information</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div><h1>Client Information</h1><table border="1">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>First Name</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="FirstName" value="" size="50" /></td>
                        <td>Surname</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="Surname" value="" size="50"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Age</td>
                        <td><input type="number" name="Age" value="" min="0" max="120"/></td>
                        <td>Gender</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="Gender" value="" size="1" maxlength="1"/></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="validation" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is the ClientInformationServlet.java file, most important is the processRequest method, and `if (request.getParameter("validation")!= null)` line is where I am trying to have the action take place.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package clientInformation;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 *
 * @author nicolasdubus
 */
@WebServlet(name = "ClientInformationServlet", urlPatterns = {"/clientinformationservlet"})
public class ClientInformationServlet extends HttpServlet {

    /*
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Client Information</title>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");

        String sfirst = request.getParameter("FirstName");
        String ssecond = request.getParameter("SurName");
        String sAge = request.getParameter("Age");
        String sGender = request.getParameter("Gender");
        try {
            Integer age = Integer.parseInt(sAge);
            if (request.getParameter("validation") != null) {
            System.out.println("<h1>Client information is valid</h1>");
            out.println("<h1>Client</h1>");
            System.exit(0);
            }
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            out.println("<h1>Client information is invalid, please verify entries</h1>");
        }
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("</html");
        /* */
        out.close();
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>
}
```

Comment: You don't have a `<form>`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis make it an answer - it is just as simple as that.

Comment: @JoopEggen you can make an answer as well.

Comment: @msrd0 the question is already legible and can be understood as is. Please don't provide such minor edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add

```
<body><form action="/clientinformationservlet" method="POST">
```

....

```
</form></body>
```

inside the body.

Comment: While this is technically correct, you should not have a god `<form>` for all your pages.

Comment: @Luiggi: do you mean "a form by servlet". Yes, of course.

Comment: No, I mean that this pattern `<body><form ...> <!-- your whole page --> </form></body>` is a god form. And this is not a good practice.

Comment: Also, there are many java web mvc frameworks that concentrate all the actions into a single Servlet like Struts 2, Spring MVC and JSF because they implement [Front Controller Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern).

Answer (score 2):

The [HTML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.2.1) states

> The elements used to create controls generally appear inside a FORM
>   element, but may also appear outside of a FORM element declaration
>   when they are used to build user interfaces. This is discussed in the
>   section on intrinsic events. **Note that controls outside a `form` cannot
>   be successful controls.**

[A `<input>` element for `submit` is a `control`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.2.1). Therefore, if it appears outside a `<form>`, as you currently have it, clicking it won't do anything.

Nest your `<input>` elements (and whatever other display elements) within a `<form>` which specifies the `action` and `method` to use to submit your data.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to submit then you should have a `<form>` in your htmml

e.g.

```
<form name="input" action="/clientinformationservlet" method="POST">
      // your inputs
</form>
```